# Parse viso grouped shapes with Python

Tags: python, shapes, visio, group

With the following Python code, I am able to print the Text of `Documents` shapes in viso.
However, if the 'Documents' shape is grouped with a small picture, I could not get the text from the grouped shape.

Is there any sampler code to tell whether the shape is grouped in Visio?

whether a 'Documents' shape is in the grouped shape in Visio?

how to get the text of 'Documents' in the grouped shape in Visio with python code?

```py
    appVisio = win32com.client.Dispatch("Visio.Application")
    vdoc = appVisio.Documents.Open(visiofile)

    intFlags = 0
    visBBoxUprightWH = 0x1

    pagecount = vdoc.Pages.Count
    with open(outputfile, 'w') as fp:
        for p in range(pagecount):
            shps = vdoc.Pages(p+1).Shapes
            for shp in shps:
                print(shp.Name, shp.Text)
                # tell if shp is grouped
                # tell whether there is 'Documents' in it.
                # if yes, print the text of the 'Documents'
```

Answer (score 1):

If the shape is grouped then the shp will have its own shape count:

**shp.shapes.count > 1**

Comment: Almost perfect. Keep in mind that python is case sensitive. So it's Shapes and Count. and you should check for > 0, not > 1

Comment: My mistake! Careless.

Comment: Hi Paul, Many thanks for your reply! once I know whether it is a grouped shape, how could I access the grouped 'Document' shape in it?

Comment: Hi Paul, Many thanks for your reply! once I know whether it is a grouped shape, how could I access the grouped 'Document' shape in it?

Once more thing is that shp.shapes.count=17, but the shp is a ungrouped shape.
It seems that shp.shapes.count doesn't refers to group or not

Comment: Developer can make *ungrouped shape* just change value in **LockGroup** cell to ```LockGroup=1```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any sampler code to tell whether the shape is grouped in Visio?

You can define `Shape.Type property`, please look at [VisShapeTypes enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.visshapetypes).

| Constant | Value | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| visTypeGroup | 2 | A shape **that contains other shapes** |

The code that defines group shapes looks something like this:

```
# your previous code must be there
for shp in shps:
    if shp.type == 2:
        print(shp.name+" is group")
    else:
        print(shp.Name, shp.Text)

# your next code must
```

**PS** Updated code

```
def parse_names(sh, bul):
    if bul == 1:
        pref = "    "
    else:
        pref =""
              
    print(pref+sh.Name, sh.Text)

import win32com.client as w32 
visio = w32.Dispatch("visio.Application") 
visio.Visible = 1 
doc = visio.activedocument 
page = doc.pages(1) 
shps = page.Shapes
for shp in shps:
    if shp.type == 2:
        parse_names(shp, 0)
        print(shp.name+" is group, which contain shapes:")
        print("------")
        for sshp in shp.shapes:
            parse_names(sshp, 1)
            
        print("------") 
    else:
        parse_names(shp, 0)
```

Comment: Hi Surrogate,  many thanks for your reply! could you please tell me how to use that property in Python? is there any sampler code?

Comment: I modified my answer: added code which define group shapes. I think you need use **recursion algorytm** for all sub-shapes

Comment: Hi Surrogate, what member or shape in shps should be recursive?

Comment: I create example, please look at my Jupyther notebook [there](https://github.com/Surrogate-TM/surrogate-tm.github.io/blob/master/jupyterlab/iterate_shapes_per_page.ipynb)

Comment: Thanks Surrogate! your example works.

The only issue is that: 
in my visio file, the type of 'Document' grouped with a small picture is 2, but the type of pure/single 'Document' is also 2.

Comment: What you mean as `Document` ?

Comment: ‘Document’ is a shape in Visio. its shape is rectangular and with top-right corner cut. we use it put text on Visio(text is put just right under the 'Document' shape)

Comment: you mean [this one](https://i.imgur.com/8pAqNhh.png) ?

Comment: If you open VISIO and follow the following steps, you could find that object: 1) go to Work Flow Objects -3D, 2) check the 'Document' object

Comment: [This shape](https://i.imgur.com/rP8lsCW.png) ? This shape contains a dozen segments inside itself, the segments have no text…

Comment: Yes, That shape in your upper link.  My purpose is to use python API to find out all that shapes in my visio file. Do you have an example to find out all that shapes in visio?

Comment: You need that i add iteration per all pages in my jupyther notebook?

Comment: if I use the code in your notebook, the `Document` shape and the grouped shape are both iterated as their types are both 2. That is what I have always talked about.

Comment: My code does everything that needs to be done ?
I update my answer, We can close the thread...

Comment: ```Python
for shp in shps:
    if shp.type == 2:
        parse_names(shp, 0)
        print(shp.name+" is group, which contain shapes:")
        print("------")
        for sshp in shp.shapes:
            parse_names(sshp, 1)
            
```
your code tell only shape.type ==2, but both `Document` shape and grouped shape's type is 2. so your code couldn't solve this problem.

Comment: Again, I didn't understand anything without seeing a sample document.
From my observations: recursion works only one level down, I hope you can find the answer...

Comment: May be [vsdx is designed to allow a developer to programmatically alter .vsdx (Visio) diagram files](https://vsdx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) can helps ? Lool at [Selecting all or child Shapes](https://vsdx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/find_shape.html#selecting-all-or-child-shapes)