# How to extract text from shape in visio with pywin32?

Tags: python, pywin32, visio

I'm parsing many visio files to extract texts write on specific shapes.

I use the script from this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73132965/parse-viso-grouped-shapes-with-python). I just added some lines to extract informations :

```
for shp in shps:
    if shp.Type == 2:
        parse_names(shp, 2)
        print(shp.Name+" is group, which contain shapes:")
        print("-----------------------------------------")       
        for sshp in shp.Shapes:

            sshpListName.append(sshp.Name)
            sshpListText.append(sshp.Text)
            sshpListShape.append(sshp.Shapes)
            sshpListType.append(sshp.Type)

            parse_names(sshp, 1)
        print("-----------------------------------------")
    else:
        parse_names(shp, 0)
```

I obtain this :

```
My Shape.62
My Shape.62 is group, which contain shapes:
-----------------------------------------
    Sheet_green_frame.5
    Sheet_frameID.9 ￼
    Sheet_funID.6 ￼
-----------------------------------------
```

My shapes are green rectangles with only one text zone in the bottom left corner and that is the text I want.
When I print the lists I obtain :

```
Names = ['Sheet_green_frame.5', 'Sheet_frameID.9', 'Sheet_funID.6']
Text = ['', '￼', '￼']
Shape = [<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Visio 16.0 Type Library.IVShapes instance at 0x1552579577936>, <win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Visio 16.0 Type Library.IVShapes instance at 0x1552579687424>, <win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Visio 16.0 Type Library.IVShapes instance at 0x1552579577024>]
Type = [3, 3, 3]
```

When I open the file in Visio I can see the text in the data.
So I don't understand where these data could be in my text in pywin32 because with other shapes I have some informations

P.S. : The ￼ is just shown on the stack overflow post not on my prompt it's a whitespace ['', ' ', ' '].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [obj] thing means that your shapes are using *text fields* to display the text. To get the visible (displayed) text in this case, instead of `sshpListText.append(sshp.Text)` you can use:

`sshpListText.append(sshp.Characters.TextAsString)`

More about text fields [here](https://www.linkedin.com/learning/visio-tips-and-tricks/insert-text-display-fields?autoplay=true)

Comment: It's not advised to thank in comments but thank you this help me such much